# Write data into csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am crawling data from Wikipedia and it works so far. I can display it on the terminal, but I can't write it the way I need it into a csv file :-/ 
The code is pretty long, but I paste it here anyway and hope that somebody can help me.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def spider():
    url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Gro%C3%9F-_und_Mittelst%C3%A4dte_in_Deutschland'
    code = requests.get(url).text  # Read source code and make unicode
    soup = BeautifulSoup(code, "lxml")  # create BS object

    table = soup.find(text="Rang").find_parent("table")
    for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
        partial_url = row.find_all('a')[0].attrs['href']
        full_url = "https://de.wikipedia.org" + partial_url
        get_single_item_data(full_url)          # goes into the individual sites


def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    page = requests.get(item_url).text  # Read source code & format with .text to unicode
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")  # create BS object
    def getInfoBoxBasisDaten(s):
        return str(s) == 'Basisdaten' and s.parent.name == 'th'
    basisdaten = soup.find_all(string=getInfoBoxBasisDaten)[0]

    basisdaten_list = ['Bundesland', 'Regierungsbezirk:', 'Höhe:', 'Fläche:', 'Einwohner:', 'Bevölkerungsdichte:',
                        'Postleitzahl', 'Vorwahl:', 'Kfz-Kennzeichen:', 'Gemeindeschlüssel:', 'Stadtgliederung:',
                        'Adresse', 'Anschrift', 'Webpräsenz:', 'Website:', 'Bürgermeister', 'Bürgermeisterin',
                        'Oberbürgermeister', 'Oberbürgermeisterin']

    with open('staedte.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Bundesland', 'Regierungsbezirk:', 'Höhe:', 'Fläche:', 'Einwohner:', 'Bevölkerungsdichte:',
                        'Postleitzahl', 'Vorwahl:', 'Kfz-Kennzeichen:', 'Gemeindeschlüssel:', 'Stadtgliederung:',
                        'Adresse', 'Anschrift', 'Webpräsenz:', 'Website:', 'Bürgermeister', 'Bürgermeisterin',
                        'Oberbürgermeister', 'Oberbürgermeisterin']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()

        for i in basisdaten_list:
            wanted = i
            current = basisdaten.parent.parent.nextSibling
            while True:
                if not current.name:
                    current = current.nextSibling
                    continue
                if wanted in current.text:
                    items = current.findAll('td')
                    print(BeautifulSoup.get_text(items[0]))
                    print(BeautifulSoup.get_text(items[1]))
                    writer.writerow({i: BeautifulSoup.get_text(items[1])})

                if '<th ' in str(current): break
                current = current.nextSibling


print(spider())
```

The output is incorrect in 2 ways. The cells are their right places and only one city is written, all others are missing. It looks like this:

[image]

But it should look like this + all other cities in it:

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the output?

Comment: I have made a screenshot. You can easily test it with the code, it works in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

**'... only one city is written ...'**: You call `get_single_item_data` for each city. Then inside this function you open the output file with the same name, in the statement `with open('staedte.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:` which will overwrite the output file each time you call the function.

**Each variable is written to a new row**: In the statement `writer.writerow({i: BeautifulSoup.get_text(items[1])})` you write the value for one variable to a row. What you need to do instead is to make a dictionary for values before you start looking for page values. As you accumulate the values from the page you shove them into the dictionary by field name. Then after you have found all of the values available you call `writer.writerow`.